# Radon-Nikodym Density $\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}/\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}$ if distribution of r.v. $X$ is known under $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

**Assumptions**

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ two equivalent probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.

Suppose $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a real-valued random variable with pdf $f_X^{\mathbb{P}}>0$ under $\mathbb{P}$ and $f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}>0$ under $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Question**

Is it true that the Radon-Nikodym Density $\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}/\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q}$ is given by

$$\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}/\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q} = \frac{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(X)}{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(X)}>0? $$

So far, I could figure out that it, first, has expectation under $\mathbb{Q}$ equal to 1:

$$ \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\left[\frac{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(X)}{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(X)} \right] = \int\frac{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(X)}{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(X)} \mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q} = \int \frac{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(x)}{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(x)} f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(x) \mathrm{d}x =1.  $$

and that, second, for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ it holds

$$ \mathbb{P}(A) = \int_A \mathrm{d} \mathbb{P} = \int_A \frac{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(X)}{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(X)} \frac{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(X)}{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(X)} \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} = \int_{A}  \frac{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(X)}{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(X)} \mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\left[\frac{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(X)}{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(X)}\mathbf{1}_A\right].$$

Yet, I'm not sure whether this is enough as proof (I'm not a measure theory expert).

**Background**

Let $\mu>r>0$, $\sigma>0$ and $T>0$ and $X$ be lognormal distributed in the following way

- under $\mathbb{P}$: $X\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\sim} \mathrm{LN}((\mu-1/2\sigma^2)T,\sigma\sqrt{T})$, and
- under $\mathbb{Q}$: $X\overset{\mathbb{Q}}{\sim} \mathrm{LN}((r-1/2\sigma^2)T,\sigma\sqrt{T})$

Then
$\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}/\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q} = \frac{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(X)}{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(X)} = \mathrm{exp}(\kappa Z -1/2\kappa^2T)$ where $Z \overset{\mathbb{Q}}{\sim} N(0,\sqrt{T})$ and $\kappa = (\mu-r)/\sigma$.

If the claim above was true, I could also compute the change of measure for different $\sigma$ under the two measures, i.e., $X\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\sim} \mathrm{LN}((\mu-1/2\sigma_1^2)T,\sigma_1\sqrt{T})$ and $X\overset{\mathbb{Q}}{\sim} \mathrm{LN}((r-1/2\sigma_2^2)T,\sigma_2\sqrt{T})$,  as
$$\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}/\mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q} = \frac{f_X^{\mathbb{P}}(X)}{f_X^{\mathbb{Q}}(X)}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu,\nu$ be probability measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $\mu,\nu$ with respective $\lambda$-densities $f_\mu,f_\nu>0$ ($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure). For all $A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$\int_A d\mu =\int_A f_\mu d\lambda = \int_A \frac{f_\mu}{f_\nu}f_\nu d\lambda=\int_A \frac{f_\mu}{f_\nu}d\nu$$
so it follows that
$$\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}=\frac{f_\mu}{f_\nu}\quad \nu\textrm{-a.e.}$$
and equivalently $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=\frac{f_\nu}{f_\mu}$ $\mu$-a.e. So $\mu,\nu$ are equivalent probability measures.

---

Now let $\mu,\nu$ be probability measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $\mu,\nu$ with respective $\lambda$-densities $f_\mu,f_\nu>0$. Consider $(\Omega,\sigma(X))$ for a measurable function $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and probability measures $P,Q$. If $X\stackrel{P}{\sim}\mu,\,X\stackrel{Q}{\sim}\nu$ we have
$$\int_{X^{-1}(A)}P(d\omega)=\int_{X^{-1}(A)}\frac{f_\mu(X(\omega))}{f_\nu(X(\omega))}Q(d\omega),\forall A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
So
$$\frac{dP}{dQ}=\frac{f_\mu(X)}{f_\nu(X)}\quad Q\textrm{-a.e.}$$
Furthermore:
$$\int_{X^{-1}(A)}Q(d\omega)=\int_{X^{-1}(A)}\frac{f_\nu(X(\omega))}{f_\mu(X(\omega))}P(d\omega),\forall A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
So
$$\frac{dQ}{dP}=\frac{f_\nu(X)}{f_\mu(X)}\quad P\textrm{-a.e.}$$
and therefore $P,Q$ are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear answer which helps me a lot! I only have one small question out of personal interest: You assumed the measurable space to be $(\Omega,\sigma(X))$. So for a bigger sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ the statement does not hold in general as I cannot express all events in $\mathcal{F}$ as preimages under $X$, I guess?

Comment: You're welcome @MWilk. Indeed that measurable space makes the above argument work, but I wouldn't exclude possible extensions.

Comment: Perfect thank you!